# Find the differential equation in partial derivatives that follows from: $f(x+y+z)=xyz$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Find the differential equation in partial derivatives that follows from:

$$f(x+y+z)=xyz$$

Idea: If $u(x,y,z)=x+y+z$ and $v(x,y,z)=xyz$ then

$$\phi(u,v):=f(u)-v=0,$$ hence,

$$\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=f^\prime(u)+yz\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial v}$$ $$\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=f^\prime(u)+xz\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial v}$$

I think this is not the way to solve the problem, can someone help me please?

Comment: If you have no information about $f$, you can't eliminate it from the equation. Are you sure you have quoted the problem correctly and in full?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question - there is no $f$ such satisfies $f(x+y+z)=xyz$ for all $x,y,z$.

Comment: This is not clear.  There is no function $F$ such that $F(x+y+z)=xyz$ for all real numbers $x,y,z$.  If there were than $F(x)=F(x+0+0)=0\implies F(x)$ constant, which is absurd.

Comment: What do you mean by "eliminate the function $f$"? Are you asking to solve $f$?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  As it stands, it really doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry, I did not write well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x+y+z)=xyz\quad\text{or}\quad g(xyz)=x+y+x$$
with $f$ and $g$ inverse functions one to the other.

We are looking for a first order linear PDE on the general form :
$$\alpha(x,y,z)\frac{\partial F(x,y,z)}{\partial x}+\beta(x,y,z)\frac{\partial F(x,y,z)}{\partial y}+\gamma(x,y,z)\frac{\partial F(x,y,z)}{\partial z}=0$$
In order to simplify the editing we will use the notations :
$$\alpha F_x+\beta F_y+\gamma F_z=0$$

Moreover we look for $\alpha(x,y,z),\beta(x,y,z),\gamma(x,y,z)$ so that the above functions
$$u=x+y+z \text{ and } v=xyz$$
be the equations of characteristic curves so that the relationship $f(u)=v$ be satisfied.

If so, the general solution of the PDE is on the form of implicit equation :

$$F(x,y,z)=\Phi\big(u,v\big)=\Phi\big((x+y+z),(x,y,z)\big)$$

We compute the partial derivatives :
$$F_x=\Phi_u+yz\Phi_v$$
$$F_y=\Phi_u+xz\Phi_v$$
$$F_z=\Phi_u+xy\Phi_v$$
From the three equations one can eliminate $\Phi_u$ and $\phi_v$ which leads to the next relationship :
$$\boxed{x(z-y)F_x+y(x-z)F_y+z(y-x)F_z=0}$$
So, the coefficients of the PDE are determined :
$$\alpha=x(z-y)$$
$$\beta=y(x-z)$$
$$\gamma=z(y-x)$$